# Resultados diferente entre localhost e no servidor

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Tenho a consulta abaixo que funciona direitinho em localhost mas quando manda para o servidor não funciona

O que pode ser?

```
    SELECT CONCAT( mes, '/ ', ano ) AS data, IFNULL( SUM( total ) , 0 ) AS Total
FROM lc_controle
WHERE tipo_venda ='Atacado' AND tipo ='0'
group by mes, ano Order By ano, mes
```

Resultado em localhost:

```
    data
Total
1/ 2017
82950.23
2/ 2017
60386.26
3/ 2017
118314.10
4/ 2017
91309.18
5/ 2017
105705.88
6/ 2017
47475.58
7/ 2017
169589.50
8/ 2017
173758.04
9/ 2017
95056.97
10/ 2017
256681.42
11/ 2017
222838.47
12/ 2017
85775.08
```

Resultado no servidor:

```
    data
Total
312f2032303137
82950.23
322f2032303137
60386.26
332f2032303137
118314.10
342f2032303137
91309.18
352f2032303137
105705.88
362f2032303137
47475.58
372f2032303137
169589.50
382f2032303137
173758.04
392f2032303137
95056.97
31302f2032303137
256681.42
31312f2032303137
222838.47
31322f2032303137
87318.40
312f2032303138
39141.66
```

As versões são quase as mesmas

Localhost:

phpMyAdmin Informação da versão: 4.6.6

versão do PHP: 5.6.30

Servidor:

Versão do servidor: 5.1.68

Apache
Versão do cliente de base de dados: libmysql - 5.1.73

phpMyAdmin
Informação de Versão: 4.0.10.15

Comment: lembrou de configurar as variaveis de conexão com o banco de dados no seu sistema?

Comment: Sim, os arquivos são os mesmos, só o resultado está diferente

Comment: Altamente recomendo que atualize esse servidor, a versão do **PHP** para no mínimo **5.6**